# My passed-away grandmother

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Is correct to say 'I dreamt that my passed-away grandmother returned back to my home...' (as I dreamt about the time when she was alive, not returned as a ghost)?

I don't feel like to say 'my died grandmother', I feel that sounds bad.

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot say my passed away grandfather as passed away isn't an adjective; it's the past and the past participle form of the verb. You can say my dear late/departed/dead grandfather to show respect to your grandfather.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the person I am speaking to knows my grandmother was dead, I would just say:

> my grandmother

If the person did not know, I would still say the same unless the topic is related to her passing. In that case:

> my **late** grandmother

[late](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/late):

> 5) having recently died

Definitely not "my *dead* grandmother", which would be disrespectful.

There are various other phrases, for example "my dear departed grandmother".

Comment: One could also use my *deceased* grandmother